# Average channels of convolutional layer keras

Tags: python, keras

I have a problem. I have built a ConvNet. One hidden before the final output the shape of the output of that hidden layer is (None,64,32,32). What I want is to take the element wise average of those 64 channels. I have tried this:

```
main_inputs=[]
outputs=[]

def convnet(channels,rows,columns):
        input=Input(shape=(channels,rows,columns))
        main_inputs.append(input)
        conv1=Convolution2D(kernel_size=(3,3) ,filters=64, padding="same")(input)
        activation1= Activation('relu')(conv1)
        conv2=Convolution2D(kernel_size=(3,3), filters=64, padding="same")(activation1)
        activation2 = Activation('relu')(conv2)
        conv3=Convolution2D(kernel_size=(3,3), filters=64, padding="same")(activation2)
        activation3 = Activation('relu')(conv3)
        conv4=Convolution2D(kernel_size=(3,3), filters=channels, padding="same")(activation3)
        out=keras.layers.Average()(conv4)
        activation4 = Activation('linear')(out)
        outputs.append(activation4)
        print(np.shape(outputs))
        model = Model(inputs=main_inputs, outputs=outputs)

        return model
```

But when I am getting an error:

```
ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs
```

After that instead of the keras.layer.average I tried with the backend documentation:

```
out=K.mean(conv4,axis=1)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The shape of `outputs` is `(1,)`. What do you want to average?

Comment: Yes you are right. I edited the question. The average should go after the last convolution. I want to average the channels so as to end up with a dimension of (None,1,32,32).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say `conv4` is a tensor with shape `(batch_size, nb_channels, 32, 32)`. You can average `conv4` over the channels' dimension as follows:

```
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1))(conv4)
```

The resulting tensor `out` will have shape `(batch_size, 32, 32)`. You need to wrap all the backend operations within a [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer, so that the resulting tensors are valid Keras tensors (so that they don't lack some attributes such as `_keras_history`).

If you want the shape of `out` to be `(batch_size, 1, 32, 32)` instead, you can do:

```
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1)[:, None, :, :])(conv4)
```

**NOTE:** Not tested.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect solution. Imagine if you had test it what you could answer. Thank you so much. Again awesome solution!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Add my few cents to rvinas answer - there's parameter called keepdims which prevent reducing shape of tensor after applying some operation to it.

> keepdims: A boolean, whether to keep the dimensions or not. If
>   keepdims is False, the rank of the tensor is reduced by 1. If keepdims
>   is True, the reduced dimension is retained with length 1.

```
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=1), keepdims=True)(conv4)
```

Comment: Looks like Keras has discontinued `keepdims` in Lambda